# Modificar table AspNetUserClaims Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Bom dia,

Estou com um probleminha de lógica com o identity.

Preciso criar uma tela de acesso e gostaria de usar a table claim já disponibilizada pelo mesmo. O grande problema é que a tabela cria uma chave estrangeira para a table AspNetUsers, gostaria que este campo fosse uma chave estrangeira de uma table que vou criar.

Como posso modificar esta relação entre as tabelas?

Comment: Samuel, não estou achando muito clara sua pergunta, o que você quer é que sua nova tabela tenha uma relação com a AspNetUserClaims?

Comment: Não amigo, quero que a relação que ja existe entre a claims e a users fosse apagada e criar uma nova entre a claims e outra que vou criar.

Comment: Mas pq você quer fazer isso, teria como por o código de sua classe?

Comment: A table de UserClaims cria um acesso pra cada usuário, queria criar um acesso e varios usuarios utilizar o msm. Ainda não tem muito codigo fera, ainda nao criei as telas justamente por causa deste relacionamento.

Comment: Acredito que o caminho que você está tentando seguir não esteja correto. Quando tiver as classes de seu modelo, edite a pergunta e coloque elas.

Comment: Como posso fazer então? Já tenho as classes de cadastro de usuario, cadastro de empresa. Eu iria criar as telas de cadastro de acesso agr, mas ai surgiu este probleminha de relacionamento.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43359/discussion-between-pablo-vargas-and-samuel-phellip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está usando ASP.NET Identity, o correto é sua entidade de `Usuario` herdar de `IdentityUser`:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser { ... }
```

A configuração de nomenclatura de tabelas pode ser mudada através do evento `OnModelCreating` usando *Fluent API*:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Usuario>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Usuarios", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UsuarioId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .ToTable("Usuarios", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UsuarioId");
    }
}
```

Analogamente, isso pode ser feito para `IdentityUserClaim`:

```
public class UsuarioIdentificacao : IdentityUserClaim { ... }
```

E a configuração:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("UsuarioIdentificacoes", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UsuarioIdentificacaoId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioIdentificacao>()
            .ToTable("UsuarioIdentificacoes", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UsuarioIdentificacaoId");
```

Comment: Eu estou fazendo isso, mas nao sei como remover a foreign key da table AspNetUsersClaims.

Comment: Mas por que você quer isso? Qual o problema com a tabela de Claims?

Comment: É que a table de claims tem uma chave estrangeira com a table user, queria que essa chave estrangeira estivesse com outra table que vou criar, assim vários usuarios poderão usar a mesma claim. Como se fosse um tipo de cadastro de funções, aí estas funções teriam as claims.

Comment: Ué, mas é só derivar a classe `IdentityUserClaim` e colocar tudo lá. É análogo.

Comment: Isso que não sei fazer rs como faço isso?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado Cigano!

Comment: Veja agora. Acho que tem tudo.

Comment: Cara, que simples, achei que seria um tanto de código. Muito obrigado! AJudou demais...