# Alterar nomes de colunas de tabelas criadas pelo Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

A minha dúvida é simples, porém não estou conseguindo resolver. É possível alterar o nome das colunas da tabela **AspNetUsers** que o Identity cria na base de dados?

Outra dúvida é, como adicionar novos campos nesta mesma tabela sendo que uma delas será relacionada com uma outra tabela?

Estou trabalhando com Entity Framework Code First.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> É possível alterar o nome das colunas da tabela AspNetUsers que o Identity cria na base de dados?

Não. O nome das colunas é essencial para uma verificação de segurança feita por `IdentityDbContext` na inicialização do contexto ([veja aqui das linhas 127 a 132](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-rtm-140221/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework)).

Você pode mudar o nome das tabelas, se quiser. [Explico isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144051/2999).

> Outra duvida é, como adicionar novos campos nesta mesma tabela sendo que uma delas será relacionada com uma outra tabela?

Derivando a entidade:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser 
{
    public String InformacaoNova1 { get; set; }
    public String InformacaoNova2 { get; set; }
    public String InformacaoNova3 { get; set; }
}
```

E tipando o contexto com a sua classe `Usuario`:

```
public class MeuContexto : IdentityDbContext<Usuario> { ... }
```

[Eu faço uma demonstração de como alterar mais alguns aspectos do ASP.NET Identity aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWmT9R_ZthY).

Comment: Obrigado Cigano Morrison. Ótimas dicas nos links apresentados.